# Generic constraint inherit from generic base

Tags: c#, generics

Sorry for the unclear title, I hope someone can clarify.

I want to create a generic interface where I need to have the generic type `T` inherit from a base class, but the base class is also a generic type: `Base<U>`. Is there a way to specify that `T` needs to inherit from `Base` without needing `U` to be specified as well?

Example:

```
public interface ICommentRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T>
    where T : Comment<U>, new()
```

I don't care about `U` so I don't want `ICommentRepository<T, U>`. And this would make implementations awkward as well:

```
public class ArticleCommentRepository : ICommentRepository<Comment<Article>, Article> { .. }
```

having to supply `Article` twice.

Comment: Define a non-generic `Base` (which need not contain anything if there's nothing that's non-generic and meaningful to put there, and might also be an `IBase`) and have `Base<U>` inherit from that. Of course, if you actually need information on what `Base<U>` the type inherits from that gets awkward, but then you probably need to revisit your hierarchy anyway. Constraints are often added even if they don't actually add anything in terms of type safety.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks. If you add that as an answer, I can accept it. No other takers so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on why you need `U` for? If you don't need it for constraint you can easily create non generic base and use that as your constraint

```
public class Base
{

}

public class Base<T> : Base
{

}

public interface ICommentRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T>
    where T : Base, new()
{

}
```

You can even do something like this if you generic constraint is not important but you still need to use generic base constraint

```
public interface ICommentRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T>
        where T : Base<object>, new()
{

}
```

If you could post more details about `Base<T>` and why it's generic, it can help us resolve your issue.

Cheers!

Comment: This is close to what I ended up doing, but I went with a `IBase` interface instead. The `Base<U>` class needs `U` as a return type a on method which will not be used by the Repository interfaces or implementation. I extracted the non-generic methods that are used by the Repository to the non-generic `IBase` interface.

Comment: Exactly the idea! And even better if you used interfaces instead of classes for constraints as in my answer.